# Can Not Redirect from Application-BeginRequest at First Request using RewritePath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I want to redirect to a maintenance screen when we are inside the defined maintenance window (between Start DateTime and End DateTime)

inside my Global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var maintStart = Convert.ToDateTime(CommonUtilities.GetAppConfigCredential("MaintenanceStartDateTime"));
    var maintEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(CommonUtilities.GetAppConfigCredential("MaintenanceEndDateTime"));
    DateTime nw = DateTime.Now;

    if (maintStart < nw && nw < maintEnd)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("MaintenancePage");
    }
}
```

If I start up my application outside the maintenance window, then wait until the window start DateTime (or simply change the config), I get redirected to the maintenance screen on the next request.  However, if I try to start up my application during the maintenance window, i get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
```

Not sure how to debug this, or what my next step should be.

**EDIT:**

If I start up my application inside the maintenance window, I need:

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Home/MaintenancePage");
```

to make it work properly.

If I start up my application outside the maintenance window, then wait until the maintenance window start time, I need:

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("MaintenancePage");
```

to make it work properly.

**EDIT2:**

Forgot to mention, I have this:

```
public ActionResult MaintenancePage()
{
    return View();
}
```

in my HomeController.

And I forgot to mention that the Maintenance Page was in the Views/Home folder.

Comment: 99% you redirect maintenance page to itself indefinitely. Hard to say for sure without knowing where you actually redirect to.

Comment: @Alexi - no, it doesn't work that way with Rewritepath.

Comment: @Alexi - `RewritePath` doesn't redirect.  Therefore, it doesn't generate additional `BeginRequest` events.

Comment: Does your code contain other calls to `RewritePath`?

Comment: @Amy - no.  What you see is what I got.  I think the key is the two different paths that i specified in my edit.

Comment: I recommend adding a logging statement to the top of your BeginRequest method.  Just log out the session id.  Then boot up your application so it will error.  When a app pool starts up, it creates your Application class (global_asax) twice (by design).  I am wondering if that is happening to you here.  If so, you'll see two logging messages.  Google "global asax twice" for more info on this idea.

Comment: I doubt my previous comment is what is happening in your case, but I want to rule it out as a possibility.

Comment: @Amy - I'm still in the development phase, so in VisualStudio with breakpoints I can see the BeginRequest called twice.

Comment: Okay, then it is entirely possible that *is* your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162108/discussion-between-joe-and-amy).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot access Chat from work, so I'll be a little late to the conversation.  I will join later this evening though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Global.asax.cs file, in Application_BeginRequest, this is the correct statement, with the correct path:

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/Home/MaintenancePage");
```